# How to fix 'has no exported member 'VeiwChild'' error in Ionic

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I am trying to import google maps into my ionic 2 application. And so far all everything works. the problem arises with me importing the VeiwChild pack from @angular/core. Hence everytime I run the code it gives me the same error.

` Module '"C:/Users/Jay/Documents/maps/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'VeiwChild'.

C:/Users/Jay/Documents/maps/src/pages/home/home.ts

import { Component, VeiwChild } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; `

Here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
 
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0i4Rwgm2oyIOevkQNPydd1BwXJOV2WBk"></script>
  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the home.html code

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

this is my home.scss code

```css
page-home {
    .ios, .md {

        home-page {

          .scroll {
            height: 100%
          }

          #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }

        }

    }

}
```

And finally here is my home.ts code

```js
import { Component, VeiwChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 @VeiwChild('map') mapElement;
 map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionVeiwDidLoad()
  {
   this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){
 
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);
 
    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
 
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
 
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why i keep on getting this error. This is the video i used as reference.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yNJ-QrHvgc)

Answer (score 2):

Its just a typo.

This:

```
import { Component, VeiwChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Should be this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

`View` NOT `Veiw`

NOTE: It is also misspelled in several other places, such as here:

```
@VeiwChild('map') mapElement;
```

Comment: You got some other misspellings of veiw.  I'd recommend using an editor that can check you syntax like visual studio code

Comment: Did you mean to add your comment to my answer? Or to the original question?

Comment: I guess to the original...I just wanted to add to your comment not because you have a typo. @VeiwChild('map') is wrong also.

Comment: Ah. Should I add that to my answer?

Comment: up to you :)...He should be using an IDE that will tell him, not a person from stackoverflow.

Comment: Yep. Very true.